# What does declaring { get } with a property imply?

Tags: swift

I came across a piece of code that had a property declared like this:

```
var category: String { get }
```

What does it signify? can we also declare such a property in a class and not in a protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line expresses the requirement of conforming types to have a variable called `category`, of type `String`, with at *least* a getter.

Such a requirement could be satisfied in a conforming type with a `let` constant, a `var` variable, or a computed `var`.

Comment: Why answer a duplicate?